# Adding Custom-Template to TextBox, TextBox Cannot "Set" values anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

When I use this template, the TextBox loses its function to set. If I delete the style, its works perfectly. Why is that?

Code for Resource Dictionary

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
       x:Key="InputTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#F46D1E"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            Height="50"
                            Width="190"
                            CornerRadius="4"
                            Margin="10,15,15,15">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox     x:Name="inputText"
                                         Background="Transparent"
                                         BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                         Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                         TextAlignment="Left"
                                         Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Code for View

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <Label
                        Content="{Binding User1.Name}"
                        Style="{StaticResource InputLabel}"/>
                    <TextBox
                        Style="{StaticResource InputTextBox}"
                        Text="{Binding User1.Name, FallbackValue= Something}"
                        />
```

Comment: A TextBox in the ControlTemplate of a TextBox makes no sense. There should be `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />`. See [TextBox Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, Clemens. Actually, that solved my problem. But what's the reason for not adding a TextBox inside the control template? In the template, should only elements need to be "changed"?

Comment: A TextBox in a TextBox are two TextBoxes.